# IND-CCA2 post-quantum key exchange

Tags: key-exchange, post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

QUIC requires that servers reuse keys so that session resumption works.  That breaks many post-quantum key exchange systems.

I am looking for a post-quantum key exchange algorithm with the following properties:

- Fast (Lattice-based)
- IND-CCA2
- The chosen key depends on randomness from **both** parties (this is important for many uses of channel binding).

Comment: I believe [Supersingular isogeny key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersingular_isogeny_key_exchange) meets the criteria that it's fast, post-quantum-secure and is random. I couldn't find any references to IND-CCA2 for Supersingular isogeny key exchange, though - which is why I wrote this comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @AleksanderRassasse CCA2 ist a security notion for public key encryption anyways. Chances are a IES style construction will work to construct one.

Comment: @SEJPM Did you mean "CCA2 is *not* a security notion for public key encryption"? If so, why is that?

PS: not sure if this should be a separate question :)

Comment: @zoresvit I meant exactly what I said. CCA2 _is_ a security notion for (public-key) encryption. Key-Exchange algorithms themselves _are not_ directly encryption algorithms, thus CCA2 doesn't apply to them (case in point: Diffie-Hellman). But using an [IES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Encryption_Scheme)-style approach we can _probably_ construct a CCA2-secure encryption scheme from the key exchange.

Comment: Now I'm clear, thanks for the explanation!

PS: The reason I asked was that I wasn't sure if "ist" was a typo of "is" or "isn't", and additional context also helped.

Comment: I assume you aren't going to be using forward secrecy then?

Comment: Also, check out https://www.safecrypto.eu/pqclounge/round-2-candidates/ and text search for "CCA2".

Comment: @forest I *do* want forward secrecy.  However, many existing protocols, such as TLS1.3, rely on the CCA security of ECDH (in that case for session resumption).

Answer (score 1):

NewHope is a key-exchange protocol based on the Ring-Learning-with-Errors (Ring-LWE) problem.

NewHope512-CCA-KEM and NewHope1024-CCA-KEM are IND-CCA-secure key encapsulation mechanisms that target level 1 and level 5, respectively, (matching or exceeding the brute-force security of AES-128 and AES-256, respectively).

Google is working on deploying post-quantum key-agreement in TLS by combining NewHope with an existing key-agreement (X25519)as the combination CECPQ1. Please find a GoLang implementation of NewHope in [GitHub](https://github.com/Yawning/newhope).

Comment: KEM is not really key agreement, it's key establishment. Does it comply to "The chosen key depends on randomness from both parties (this is important for many uses of channel binding)." ?